# How to make const for whole file?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

is there some way to make const for whole file? For example, get categoryId const, so that it can be used for `message.channel.send(categoryId)`

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'new',
    description: "Vytvoří novou sekci pro zákazníka",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client, chalk){
        message.guild.channels.create(` | ${args[0]}`, { type: 'category' })
        .then(category => {const categoryId = (category.id)})
    
        message.channel.send(categoryId)
    }
}
```

Comment: Under execute you set a const file and you can use it for the rest of your code . If you want a const file that will cover the whole code , then you need above of module.exports , to set the const file of your desire !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just declare it at the top of the file. However in your case, `let` would be more fitting than `const`, as you have to assign a value to a `const` when creating it, so your solution would look like this:

```js
let categoryID;
module.exports = {
    name: 'new',
    description: "Vytvoří novou sekci pro zákazníka",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client, chalk){
        message.guild.channels.create(` | ${args[0]}`, { type: 'category' })
        .then(category => categoryID = category.id)

        message.channel.send(categoryID)
    }
}
```

I suggest you take a look at the MDN sites for [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).